# What's the state message useful for in a HTTP response message?

Tags: http

My book makes an example where the first line of the HTTP response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Then there is a table where explains all the codes, and 200 is equal to 'OK'.

Then what is the 'OK' useful for, and why is there this redundancy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means [exactly what it says in RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6.1.1), which you should have read:

> **6.1.1 Status Code and Reason Phrase**
>
> The Status-Code element is a 3-digit integer result code of the attempt to understand and satisfy the request. These codes are fully defined in section 10. The Reason-Phrase is intended to give a short textual description of the Status-Code. *The Status-Code is intended for use by automata and the Reason-Phrase is intended for the human user.* The client is not required to examine or display the Reason-Phrase.